# Basic vector spaces

Tags: vector-spaces

I'm tring to study these spaces, I have to tell if in each case, $(E,+,.)$ is an $\mathbb{R}-vecspace$

1) Let E=$\mathbb{R}^2 $$\ \forall x=(x_1,x_2), y=(y_1,y_2) \ \in  E ,\ x+y=(x_1+y_1,x_2+y_2)$

$ \forall x=(x_1,x_2) \ \in \ E, \ \alpha \ \in \mathbb{R} \ \alpha.x=(\alpha x_1,x_2)$;

We start looking if $(E,+)$ is a commutative group.

. $+$ is associative :
$(x+y)+z=(x_1+y_1,x_2+y_2)+(z_1,z_2)=(x_1+y_1+z_1,x_2+y_2+z_2)=x+(y+z)$

.+ has a neutral element n which is 0.

.each element $x \ \in E$ has a symetric for + which is -x.
And the group is commutative since x+y=y+x so $(\mathbb{R}^2,+)$ is a commutative group.

.Now let's see if $1.x=x$

Indeed $1.x=(1x_1,x_2)=(x_1,x_2)=x$ , this condition is checked.

.  $\lambda .(x+y)=(\lambda .x)+(\lambda .y)$

$\lambda .(x+y)=\lambda .(x_1+y_1,x_2+y_2)=(\lambda (x_1+y_1), x_2+y_2)=(\lambda x_1+\lambda y_1, x_2+y_2)$ which is equal to $(\lambda . x) + (\lambda . y)$. Thus this condition is checked too.

. $(\lambda + \mu).x=(\lambda . x)+(\mu .x)$

$(\lambda + \mu).x=((\lambda + \mu)x_1,x_2)=((\lambda 1 +\mu 1, \lambda 2 + \mu2)x_1,x_2)$ whereas $(\lambda . x)+(\mu .x)=(\lambda x_1 + \mu  x_1, x_2+x_2)$ So we stop here like this condition is not checked and this is not a $\mathbb{R}-vecspace$

2)Let E=$\mathbb{R}^2 $$\ \forall x=(x_1,x_2), y=(y_1,y_2) \ \in  E ,\ x+y=(x_1+y_1,x_2+y_2)$

$ \forall x=(x_1,x_2) \ \in \ E, \ \alpha \ \in \mathbb{R} \ \alpha.x=(\alpha x_1, \alpha x_2)$

We already prooved this a a commutative group, then,

.$1.x=(1x_1,1x_2)=x$ this condition is checked.

.$\lambda.(x+y)=(\lambda x_1+ \lambda y_1, \lambda x_2 + \lambda y_2)$ and $(\lambda.x)+(\lambda . y)=(\lambda x_1 + \lambda y_1 , \lambda x_2 + \lambda y_2)$ too so this condiction is checked.

. $(\lambda+\mu).x=(\lambda . x)+(\mu .x)=(\lambda x_1 + \mu x_1, \lambda x_2+ \mu x_2)$ thus this condition is checked.

.$\lambda . (\mu .x)=\lambda . (\mu x_1, \mu x_2)=(\lambda \mu x_1, \lambda \mu x_2)=(\lambda \mu).x$ thus all the conditions are checked and in this case $(\mathbb{R^2},+,.)$ is a vector space.

3) Let E=$\mathbb{R}^2 $$\ \forall x=(x_1,x_2), y=(y_1,y_2) \ \in  E ,\ x+y=(x_1+y_1,x_2+y_2)$

$ \forall x=(x_1,x_2) \ \in \ E, \ \alpha \ \in \mathbb{R} \ \alpha.x=(\alpha^2 x_1,\alpha ^2 x_2)$;

We showed this was a commutative group but one condition is not checked,

Indeed, $(\lambda + \mu).x=(\lambda 1 + \mu 1, \lambda 2 + \mu 2).x=((\lambda 1 + \mu 1)^2x_1, (\lambda 2 + \mu 2 )^2 x_2)=((\lambda 1 ^2 + 2 \lambda 1 + \mu 1 ^2)x_1 , (\lambda 2 ^2 + 2 \lambda 2 + \mu 2 ^2)x_2)$

whereas $(\lambda.x)+(\mu.x)=(\lambda ^2 x_1 + \mu ^2 x_1, \lambda ^2 x_2 + \mu ^2 x_2)$

This condition is not checked so this a not a vector space.

Haven't I made mistakes, is there just the 2) which is a vector space ?
Thank you

Comment: I think that you've made a mistake in your description of (2). You have scalar multiplication listed as $$ \alpha \cdot x = (\alpha x_1, \alpha x_2)$$ which is just ordinary scalar multiplication, but it seems that you are using something different in your proof.

Comment: That said, assuming the version that you use in your proof is the intended one, then you are 100% correct, and neither of these is a vector space for exactly the reasons that you provide.

Comment: Thank you indeed $'.'$ is just ordinary scalar multiplication, I have made some mistakes that I have corrected, however I said the 2) is a vector space, why are you assuming is not ?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed that there was a (3). I somehow thought it was a continuation of (2). Evidently reading comprehension isn't my strong suit today.